# How to use CompositeTransform in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, rendertransform

How can I code this XAML code in C#?

```
<TextBlock Text="..." RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform TranslateY="-25"/>
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
```

I tried in this way:

```
private TextBlock dots;
dots = new TextBlock();
dots.Text = "...";
dots.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5); 
(dots.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform).TranslateY = 20;
```

But I get a **System.NullReferenceException**.
I also tried in this way:

```
var ct = (CompositeTransform)dots.RenderTransform;
            ct.TranslateY = 20;
```

But I get a **System.InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform' to type 'System.Windows.Media.CompositeTransform'.)**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a new control from scratch, it's `RenderTransform` property will be an *Identity* `MatrixTransform`, so you can't cast it to `CompositeTransform`. You'd have to do it like this:

```
dots.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { TranslateY = 20 };
```